# Unable to execute sql query with user defined function

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have written a SQL query which would fetch duplicates of name and size:

```sql
SELECT t1.Filepath,
       t1.splitFilePath1(Filepath)
FROM Filemanager t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath),
                   Size
            FROM Filemanager
            GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath),
                     Size
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
ON t1.Size = t2.Size AND
   t1.splitFilePath1(Filepath) = t2.splitFilePath1(Filepath)
```

In the above query,splitFilePath1(Filepath) is a user defined function which takes Filepath as the input and returns filename.After receiving filename,I have to find duplicates of filename and size.

> Error received:
>   Near'(' :Syntax error

I am unable to understand where exactly it expects the '('.

Edit:Solved!!
Query:
    SELECT Filepath,splitFilePath1(Filepath) FROM Filemanager t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Filepath as Filepath1,splitFilePath1(Filepath),Size FROM Filemanager GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath), Size HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.Size = t2.Size AND splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath) = splitFilePath1(t2.Filepath1)

Thanks to lollato!!

Answer (score 1):

Change `t1.splitFilePath1(Filepath)` to `splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath)` and similarly for the other occurences. `t1.splitFilePath` would refer to a column in `t1` and having `()` parens after it is a syntax error.

Comment: :Now it is giving me no such column t1.splitFilePath1.Below is my edited query:SELECT Filepath,splitFilePath1(Filepath) FROM Filemanager t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath),Size FROM Filemanager GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath), Size HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.Size = t2.Size AND t1.splitFilePath1 = t2.splitFilePath1

Comment: Now it gave me error : No such column t2.Filepath :( .This is my query "SELECT Filepath,splitFilePath1(Filepath) FROM Filemanager t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath),Size FROM Filemanager GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath), Size HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.Size = t2.Size AND splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath) = splitFilePath1(t2.Filepath)"

Comment: It got solved.I have added an alias in the inner select query to the filepath and then used the alias.