# User defined functions not found in the duplicate query

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I have a query which would fetch duplicates by Name and Size.The Name would be retrieved by a user defined function `splitFilePath1(Filepath)` where `Filepath` is a column of a table.Below is my query

```
 SELECT Filepath,splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath) FROM Filemanager t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath),Size FROM Filemanager GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath), Size HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.Size = t2.Size AND t1.splitFilePath1 = t2.splitFilePath1
```

**Error: t1.splitFilePath1 not found.**

Edit 1:

```
SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath) FROM Filemanager t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Size,splitFilePath1(Filepath) FROM Filemanager GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath),Size HAVING count(*) > 1) t2 ON splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath)= splitFilePath1(t2.Filepath) AND t1.Size=t2.Size
```

**Error: t2.Filepath not found.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute sql query with user defined function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508212/unable-to-execute-sql-query-with-user-defined-function)

Answer (score 0):

Guess the `t1.splitFilePath1` should be replaced with `splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath)` in the end of your query. I think the table doesn't have the column

Comment: Edited query:"SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath)  FROM Filemanager t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Size,splitFilePath1(Filepath)  FROM Filemanager GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath),Size HAVING count(*) > 1) t2 ON splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath)= splitFilePath1(t2.Filepath) AND t1.Size=t2.Size" I am rececing t2.Filepath not found error.Yes the table doesnt have Filename column and hence I am using user defined function.

Comment: @user3264565: Append the same to your posting.

Answer (score 0):

In your (first) query, `t2` is not a table but a subquery, so you can access a column `t2.xxx` only if that column appears in that SELECT list.

To access the value of `splitFilePath1(Filepath)`, give it a name:

```sql
SELECT Filepath,
       splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath)
FROM Filemanager t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT splitFilePath1(Filepath) AS splitFilepath,
                   Size
            FROM Filemanager
            GROUP BY splitFilePath1(Filepath),
                     Size
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
ON t1.Size = t2.Size AND
   splitFilePath1(t1.Filepath) = t2.splitFilepath
```